# Azure storage Table -Issue in DateTime - Format

Tags: datetime-format, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Storage  Table . It contaiins a field LastExecutionTime as string datatype. It contains values 2018-06-25T05:45:12 . But when i try to get value from this field it returns 25/06/2018 05:45:12.
It takes our system Time Format . I declared LastExecutionTime as a String Data Type.  I get the value of LastExecutionTime (string datatype) from storage table and  store it in LUT (string datatype) using C#.  But it gives our local system datetime format.

My questions are

i. Why it is changing ? (Note: i declared as string )

ii. How can i get the same format (2018-06-25T05:45:12) which i stored in storage table ?

Comment: If the value is a string, and you need it as a string.... why parse it as a Date? Also: apps on your machine tend to show dates in your locale. Try using [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) using the right [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: If it's string all the way, I don't think it can be changed. There must be some code which converts the string to DateTime. Could you please share your code here?

Comment: I have declared  LastExecutionTime  as a string in AzureStorageTable and C# program.  I just read the azure storage table value as string only.

Comment: It seems that it is not related to Azure storage table. Please check the Azure storage table with Azure storage Explorer. If the format is correct in the Azure storage table. Please also double check it before store in the LUT. If possible, you could share your code how to retire the table records from Azure storage table and how to store it in LUT. Based on my test, I can get the correct format from azure storage table.